# wp_mail() function : hide all recipients

Tags: wordpress, email

using wordpress `wp_mail()` function, I'd like to hide all recipients.

I send the same email to severals users, and I would like each one to see just his email address, and not the others.
If they see no email address at all, it's ok too.

I googled, and had a look here, but didn't find anything, not even someone asking, like me, how to do.

The only idea I came through is to send one email to each user, but it could be very "heavy" (let's say hundreds of emails to send... if I could avoid it, would be great)

If someone can help... Thank you !

*Using WP 3.8.3*

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail#Using_.24headers_To_Set_.22From:.22.2C_.22Cc:.22_and_.22Bcc:.22_Parameters

Comment: use BCC option in mail eg; `$headers[] = "Bcc: {$email}"; wp_mail( '' , stripslashes($message_subject), $template , $headers, $mail_attachment )`

Comment: I tried using BCC, but if I set ONLY Bcc, the email isn't sent.
Using Bcc, I should use a "To" address too.

Comment: For "To" address, empty the value. and in header add the Bcc: emails. Its works for me (tested in gmail, yahoo, hotmail )